# how can I refresh another cell when change observedObject

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

When I select a cell, I want to deselect it from the other cell. After making the selection, I cannot remove the selection from the previous cell. What is the reason of this ? Sorry. I know little English.

**Enum**

```
enum Page {
    case newest
    case populer
    case iPhone
    case iPad
    case mac
    case watch
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = Page.newest
}
```

**Category Model**

```
struct Category: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var icon: String
    var color: Color
    var page: Page
}
```

**Basic Category**

```
let basicCategory = [
    Category(title: "En Yeniler", icon: "flame", color: .red, page: .newest),
    Category(title: "Popüler", icon: "star", color: .yellow, page: .populer),
]
```

**Cell**

```
struct TabView: View {
    var title: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var color: Color
     var page: Page
    @ObservedObject var macMainVM = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                
                self.macMainVM.selectedTab = self.page
            }
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: icon)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.custom("Oswald-Light", size: 14))
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .padding(5)
//I emphasize the choice here
            .background(self.macMainVM.selectedTab == self.page ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(color) : nil)
            
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

**ForEach**

```
VStack {
   ForEach(basicCategory, id: \.id) { item in
     TabView(title: item.title, icon: item.icon, color: item.color, page: item.page)
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: why are you using constant binding? Constant bindings are hard-coded values that don’t change. it’s more useful for preview purpose in Xcode.

Comment: I see. I edited my question sir.

Comment: Tried to compile, won't compile, what is `basicCategory`

Comment: @SergioBost I edited my question sir.

Comment: Your view is already updating, when you click on previous one, its border color is already white, so it feels like it’s not updating on user side.

Comment: Each cell has its own copy of the MainViewModel. They need to share the same instance

Comment: Should I create a ViewModel for each cell?
The home page has its own ViewModel and should I write a separate ViewModel for Cell? @LuLuGaGa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer with the working answer.

The problem was that you were using `@ObservedObject` instead of a `@StateObject`

Always use `@StateObject` for the parent view and `@ObservedObject` for the children view.

import SwiftUI

```
struct stackT: View {
   @StateObject var macMainVM = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           ForEach(basicCategory, id: \.id) { item in
            TabView(macMainVM: macMainVM, title: item.title, icon: item.icon, color: item.color, page: item.page)
                        }
                    }
    }
}

struct stackT_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        stackT()
    }
}


struct TabView: View {
    @ObservedObject var macMainVM: MainViewModel
    var title: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var color: Color
    let page: Page
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.macMainVM.globalTab = page
                    print(macMainVM.globalTab)
                }
            }
        }) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: icon)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.custom("Oswald-Light", size: 14))
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .padding(5)
//I emphasize the choice here
            .background(self.macMainVM.globalTab == self.page ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(color) : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(.clear))
            
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var globalTab = Page.newest

}


enum Page {
    case newest
    case populer
    case iPhone
    case iPad
    case mac
    case watch
    case none
}

struct Category: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var icon: String
    var color: Color
    var page: Page
}

let basicCategory = [
    Category(title: "En Yeniler", icon: "flame", color: .red, page: .newest),
    Category(title: "Popüler", icon: "star", color: .yellow, page: .populer),
    Category(title: "Another", icon: "book", color: .blue, page: .mac)
]
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question, you want to deselect from other cell too, hold on

Comment: Yes sir. Should I create a ViewModel for each cell? The home page has its own ViewModel and should I write a separate ViewModel for Cell?

Comment: Do you need multiple selection or single selection?

Comment: single section sir.

Comment: I'll retract my answer, have to leave for now, I will work on it again if someone else doesn't answer

Comment: @UfukKöşker updated my answer it works now

Answer (score 1):

Below are the approaches for **single selection** and **multiple selection**.

1. For single selection you can pass `Page` as Bindings to subView.
2. For multiple selection you can maintain a boolean state array, that can tell if current cell was already selected or not.

**Single Selection**

```
import SwiftUI

enum Page:String {
    case newest
    case populer
    case iPhone
    case iPad
    case mac
    case watch
}

struct Category: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var icon: String
    var color: Color
    var page: Page
}

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = Page.newest
}

struct TabView: View {
    var title: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var color: Color = .red
    var page: Page
    @Binding var macMainVM :Page
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                
                self.macMainVM = self.page
            }
        }) {
            VStack {
                
                Text("Tap")
                    .font(.custom("Oswald-Light", size: 14))
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .padding(5)
            //I emphasize the choice here
            .background(self.macMainVM == self.page ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(color) : nil)
            
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct mainView:View{
    
    let basicCategory = [
        Category(title: "En Yeniler", icon: "flame", color: .red, page: .newest),
        Category(title: "Popüler", icon: "star", color: .yellow, page: .populer),
    ]
    
    @ObservedObject var macMainVM = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(basicCategory.indices) { index in
                TabView(page: basicCategory[index].page,macMainVM: $macMainVM.selectedTab)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Multiple Selection**

```
   import SwiftUI

enum Page:String {
    case newest
    case populer
    case iPhone
    case iPad
    case mac
    case watch
}


class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = Page.newest
    var stateArray:[Bool] = []
}

struct Category: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var icon: String
    var color: Color
    var page: Page
}

struct TabView: View {

    var title: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var color: Color = Color.red

    var page: Page
    var count = 0
    var onIndex:Int

    @ObservedObject var macMainVM = MainViewModel()

    init(totalPage:Int,page:Page,onIndex:Int) {
        self.count = totalPage
        self.page = page
        self.onIndex = onIndex
        macMainVM.stateArray = [Bool](repeating: false, count: totalPage)
    }

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {

                if macMainVM.stateArray[onIndex] == false{
                    macMainVM.stateArray[onIndex] = true
                }else{
                    macMainVM.stateArray[onIndex] = false
                }

                macMainVM.selectedTab = self.page

            }
        }) {
            VStack {

                Text("Tap")
                    .font(.custom("Oswald-Light", size: 14))
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .padding(5)
            //I emphasize the choice here
            .background(macMainVM.stateArray[onIndex] ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(color) : nil)

        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct mainView:View{
    let basicCategory = [
        Category(title: "En Yeniler", icon: "flame", color: .red, page: .newest),
        Category(title: "Popüler", icon: "star", color: .yellow, page: .populer),
    ]
    //var model = MainViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(basicCategory.indices) { index in
                TabView(totalPage: basicCategory.count, page: basicCategory[index].page, onIndex: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE-:** I haven’t explained what I did in deep, because it will be  more understandable by looking into code.

Comment: your answer seems does not feet OP requirement, because he want use a model not Binding, also Binding is good for local works on View not having eye on changing some value like page, that would better using ObservableObject to track the page!

Comment: Op didn't mentioned anywhere that he only want to use model :). Also, that's the reason I mentioned it as approaches in first line itself :)

Comment: OP didn`t mentioned anywhere that he does not want shared object! ;)

Answer (score 0):

**The most Easy way:** You should just use shared object, which you are creating new one every time! I did not edit your code! I just used a shared model! that was all I done! Or you can use environmentObject, and that would also solve the issue without shared one! both way is working!

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
        
 struct ContentView: View {
            

    var body: some View {
    
            VStack {
                ForEach(basicCategory, id: \.id) { item in
                    TabView(title: item.title, icon: item.icon, color: item.color, page: item.page)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.gray)
            
        }
    }
    
    
    enum Page {
        case newest
        case populer
        case iPhone
        case iPad
        case mac
        case watch
    }
    
    class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
        static let shared: MainViewModel = MainViewModel() // <<: Here
        
        @Published var selectedTab = Page.newest
        
    }
    
    
    struct Category: Identifiable {
        
        var id = UUID()
        var title: String
        var icon: String
        var color: Color
        var page: Page
        
    }
    
    
    
    let basicCategory = [
        Category(title: "En Yeniler", icon: "flame", color: .red, page: .newest),
        Category(title: "Popüler", icon: "star", color: .yellow, page: .populer),
        Category(title: "iPhone", icon: "iphone.homebutton", color: .yellow, page: .iPhone),
        Category(title: "ipad", icon: "ipad.homebutton", color: .yellow, page: .iPad),
    ]
    
    
    struct TabView: View {
        
        let title: String
        let icon: String
        let color: Color
        let page: Page
        
        @ObservedObject var macMainVM = MainViewModel.shared // <<: Here
        
        
        var body: some View {
            
            
            
            Button(action: {
                
                withAnimation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0)) {
                    
                    macMainVM.selectedTab = page
                    
                }
            }) {
                
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: icon)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(color)
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.custom("Oswald-Light", size: 14))
                        .fixedSize()
                }
                .padding(5)
                .background(macMainVM.selectedTab == page ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(color) : nil)
                
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid use of singleton as much as you can. It’s not even pure singleton it’s singelton+ pattern that you are using.

Comment: that is not a case when we know about the object, also he can use environmentObject, that would do the same as well!

Comment: We don’t know if op requires single instance of object or not. Still if it’s required environment would be better to go with.

Comment: I mentioned both way as well, depending OP requirement